# Strange error in selenium after upgrading to chromedriver 2.28 needed for chrome 57

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After being forced to upgrading to chromedriver 2.28 to use selenium with chrome 57, I get the following error message:

```
[0313/100022.689:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
```

Any ideas on what might this be about?

Chromedriver: 2.28
Chrome: 57
Webdriver: 3.3
node: 6.10

Comment: got similar issue today. I think you should open a bug.

Comment: @rahoolm any clue, if it is a chromedriver or webdriver related problem?

Comment: seems to be with new chromedriver version, never saw it before.

Comment: Just ran into this problem as well, using Python though.

Comment: For whatever reason, re-downloading Chromedriver fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'm getting an error almost identical to this one while running h2 database console on Chrome.

Comment: what is the version of selenium web driver you are using? For me selenium 3.3.0 has similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest chrome(version 55-57) driver @https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/. This resolved problem for me.

Comment: Upgrade to latest chrome did not solve the problem for me

Comment: @materialdreams It is very BAD practice to put a negative score to one who tried to help you providing a good suggestion!
Indeed the solution suggested by Nagarjuna was fair enough!!!
In addition, I face the same problem and resolve it easy! 
Check your error message...

Comment: @AndreasVenieris Upgrading Chrome simply did not solve the problem as I actually also wrote. How did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283999/4981912) to my question. This resolved my issue.

*"Try the --disable-gpu switch. Chrome seems to have a problem with initializing the GPU. I had the same issue with Chromium (Version 57.0.2987.110) on my Arch Linux and with disabling the GPU everything works fine again."*

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this switch? I'm getting this error with NW.js.

Comment: This is a chromedriver switch. I'm not familiar with sending command line args to chromedriver with js.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was faced with the same issue before when I open some proxy in the back. Make sure you close it.