# Python: selenium-chromedriver error on new browser object

Tags: python, stdout, selenium-chromedriver

I am receiving the below error upon opening a new chromedriver object. The tests run successfully, but this error shows up in our UnitTest output and is undesirable. I would like to either resolve the error or hide it, if possible.

I feel it is important to mention that this output only shows up when running the script from the Windows terminal, not when run from the Python Console.

```
[0406/170246.792:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
```

chromedriver_test.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.Chrome()
```

I have tried

```
service_args=["--silent", "--log-level=0", --"disable-extensions", --"log-path=/PATH/TO/LOGS"]
```

also:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

I have also tried redirecting the output to NUL

`$ python chromedriver_test.py > NUL`

Windows 7
Chromedriver=2.29
Webdriver=3.3.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `--disable-gpu` switch. Chrome seems to have a problem with initializing the GPU. I had the same issue with Chromium (Version 57.0.2987.110) on my Arch Linux and with disabling the GPU everything works fine again.

Comment: How to use `--disable-gpu` option? Don't you know what means `re-downloading Chromedriver at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/`. How to use this driver. Thanks in advanve!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of Chrome

Maybe you should use another brower or another version.

See more here:

[Strange error in selenium after upgrading to chromedriver 2.28 needed for chrome 57](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759936/strange-error-in-selenium-after-upgrading-to-chromedriver-2-28-needed-for-chrome)

Comment: We are performing GUI testing on our web application and require acceptance for Chrome. I am happy with hiding this message even if it cannot be "resolved".

Answer (score 1):

There is my code. Itz works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class MyLib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```