# Selenium doesn't call web page in Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Chrome browser version 57.0.2987.110 and I'm trying to open up a web page with Selenium, only thing is it's only opening the browser with the standard website but is not opening the web page I told it to. It's not an option to change the browser, I have to work with chrome.

I get this error right here:

```
Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
```

I tried this solution so far, but it didn't work for me: [Strange error in selenium after upgrading to chromedriver 2.28 needed for chrome 57](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759936/strange-error-in-selenium-after-upgrading-to-chromedriver-2-28-needed-for-chrome)

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver;
    String PROXY;
    Proxy proxy;

    proxy = new Proxy();
    PROXY = "proxy.myproxy:8080";

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");

    proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

    driver.get("www.facebook.com");


}
```

I've just been starting with selenium and just wrote down everything really quick to try it out in main class. I know it's not pretty. Please bear with me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you confirm if this is happening because of proxy or not? could you disable the code to set proxy and run again.

Comment: Seems you are on `Linux`, any typical requirement to include `--disable-gpu`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your both selenium jars and update your chrome browser as well

Comment: I'm using maven with the dependencies
selenium-java version 3.5.3 and selenium-chrome-driver also version 3.5.3.

Also, I've already updated the browser, but still not working.